# Why does substitution terminate?

Tags: programming-languages, lambda-calculus, semantics, coq, termination

I'm formalizing some properties of lambda calculus in Coq and I have some problems proving termination of substitution. My terms are defined as:

```
Inductive Term :=
  TVar: nat -> Term
| TAbs: nat -> Term -> Term
| TApp: Term -> Term -> Term.
```

and I have a way of generating fresh variables using a function

```
fresh: Term -> nat
```

satisfying:

```
Lemma fresh_is_fresh:
  forall t,
    ~ FV t (fresh t).
```

and similarly a function `fresh2: Term -> Term -> nat` for obtaining a fresh identifier wrt. two terms.

I now want to define a standard notion of capture avoiding substitution:

```
Fixpoint substitute (t1:Term) (t2:Term) (x:nat): Term :=
  match t1 with
  | TVar y =>
    if beq_nat x y then t2 else TVar y
  | TApp t11 t12 =>
    TApp (substitute t11 t2 x) (substitute t12 t2 x)
  | TAbs y t =>
    if beq_nat x y then
      TAbs x t
    else TAbs (fresh2 t t1) (substitute (substitute t (TVar y) (fresh2 t t1)) t2 x)
  end.
```

Obviously, Coq cannot see that this definition is terminating, so I need to provide a custom measure, so that the code is something like the following:

```
Program Fixpoint substitute (t1:Term) (t2:Term) (x:nat) {measure ???}: Term :=
  match t1 with
  | TVar y =>
    if beq_nat x y then t2 else TVar y
  | TApp t11 t12 =>
    TApp (substitute t11 t2 x) (substitute t12 t2 x)
  | TAbs y t =>
    if beq_nat x y then
      TAbs x t
    else TAbs (fresh2 t t1) (substitute (substitute t (TVar y) (fresh2 t t1)) t2 x)
  end.
```

Now my question is: What is the correct measure to use here? And how I do use it to prove the obligations which arise using this measure?

Comment: This seems to be mostly a (good) technical question about theorem proving in Coq. I think it's better to move it to Stackoverflow.

Comment: It might be easier to differentiate between arbitrary substitution and renaming a variable.

Comment: That did the trick, @DerekElkins! I'll post an answer to my question in a second!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derek Elkins' comment solved my problem! Here's the solution I came up with:

We create a seperate renaming function `rename: Term -> nat -> nat -> Term`, which assumes that the name to rename with is fresh. This makes it trivially terminating.

```
Fixpoint rename (t:Term) (x y : nat): Term :=
  match t with
  | TVar z =>
    if beq_nat y z then TVar x
    else TVar z
  | TApp t1 t2 =>
    TApp (rename t1 x y) (rename t2 x y)
  | TAbs z t =>
    if beq_nat y z then
      TAbs z t
    else
      TAbs z (rename t x y)
  end.
```

we then define a (somewhat arbitrary) measure of a term:

```
Fixpoint size (t:Term): nat :=
  match t with
    TVar _ => 1
  | TApp t1 t2 => size t1 + size t2
  | TAbs x t => 2 + size t
  end.
```

and we can easily prove that renaming preserves this measure:

```
Lemma rename_preserves_size:
  forall t x y,
    size t = size (rename t x y).
```

this lemma is used in the final case of substitition in order to prove that the term `rename t y' y` has the same size as `t` and thus the call `substitute (rename t y' y) t2 x` happens on a strictly smaller term.

Now *all* I need to prove that this is correct.